# Can't make project, unrecognized command line option libc++ error

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, compilation, makefile

I keep getting this error message while trying to Make [this Azteroids project](https://github.com/rodrigosetti/azteroids): "c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’"

Based on what I've seen online, people are saying it's a Clang flag and the C++11 flag looks different. I mean, I don't disagree, but the instructions for creating the Azteroids executable are pretty simple and CMake seems to recognize C++11 support.

Is this a shortcoming of the cmake system in this project or am I missing a dependency or step? I don't understand. And yes, I've seen the similar questions.

Please see [this Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0TnQzszA) for more both the CMake and Make output.

Comment: Clang and C++11 are not opposites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in that output indicates that clang is involved here at all. Which is likely the problem.

It would seem that `-stdlib=libc++` is a clang flag that your GNU `c++` binary does not understand. Those flags are being manually added by the cmake configuration of that project. Which means it will not work without clang. So either remove those flags or install clang and configure cmake to use it.

Comment: Fond the sudo update-alternatives --config c++ command and changed it to Clang. Now I'm getting a OpenGL/gl.h not found error despite it being installed. Good tip, just trying to get this next step working now.

Comment: @Stradigos Do you have the `OpenGL` headers/etc. installed?

Comment: Yeah. I guess the folder in /usr/include is just "GL" and not "OpenGL". Was kind of a pain, but I replaced each include line with "GL/gl.h" and it compiled fine. I guess a more elegant solution would have been create a softlink in /usr/include but oh well.

Comment: No, symlink's in system directories are **never** the right answer.

Comment: It's frustrating that one package would name this folder GL while another would name it OpenGL. How could I please both without two complete copies of the same folder?

Comment: That's a very good question. I don't know why that path would differ. I would expect it should be standardized. I don't know why that would differ on OS X. But ideally the code would just use `<gl.h>` I suppose and let the compiler get a `-I` flag for the right location... but that may not actually be a good idea with a filename as "common" as `gl.h`.

Comment: Yeah exactly. Thanks for the help today, Etan. Definitely learned a few things.